# Occasional java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError on Android

Tags: android, noclassdeffounderror

I use a crash reporting tool that stack traces when an exception is thrown. Now and then I see a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` and I usually never pay attention to them because it's just 1 crash for every 10.000 sessions or more. The odd thing is:

1. It's usually with different classes (i.e. `NoClassDefFoundError` for class `MyAwesomeClass` and `MyOtherAwesomeClass`), it rarely happens twice for the same class.
2. The crash usually happens only once to the same user (i.e. no user has had more than one `NoClassDefFoundError` for the same class).
3. I have never been able to reproduce the error.

Now my question is: Could this be a 'device specific issue' i.e. something that Android manufacturer X could have done wrong? Could it be an OS issue?

Has anyone ever had a similar problem? Any theories on why this could happen?

Comment: Are you sure that it is indeed an appropriate error report since you are doing some crash reporting tool?  Meaning are you sure that the tool itself is not problematic.  Users have actually mentioned that this has crashed or the Play Store has indicated so?

Comment: Since it's so few users and the problem is not persistent I have not received any reports from users. I do not think the crash reporting tool is to blame as it is a very widely used option (Crashlytics).

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced `NoClassDefFoundError` in my projects. This error was thrown when I was running my app on lower version of android like 2.2 and my app uses `apis` that were not avaiable on lower version of android for example if I am trying to run my code using `Fragments` on lower version of android or my class declare some Event Listener or code related with NFC etc. that is not available on that android version on which I am running my app.

So to avoid this error may be you can use android version check in your code at places where you are using apis that are not available in lower android version.